# MySQL: change column type using expression

Tags: mysql, alter-table

In a MySQL database, I need to convert some UUID columns (`BINARY(16)`) into `VARCHAR`. I want to convert them in the canonical form, not as bytes. For clarity, in lowercase and with hyphens, and not in the `0xHEXADECIMAL` format.

In Postgres, this is enough:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ALTER COLUMN my_uuid_column
  TYPE VARCHAR(36);
```

The MySQL equivalent returns an error:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  MODIFY COLUMN my_uuid_column
  TYPE VARCHAR(36);

ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\x.....' for column 'my_uuid_column' at row 1
```

And even if it worked, the result wouldn't really be in canonical form.

I know that in Postgres I can resolve this with `USING expression`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION foobar(foo uuid) returns VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS $$
  SELECT 'foobar' -- format the UUID using some helpers.
$$;

ALTER TABLE my_table
  ALTER COLUMN my_uuid_column
  TYPE VARCHAR(36)
  USING foobar(my_uuid_column);
```

And it does what you'd expect.

I can't find a way to do something similar in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing out $tompave's Comment; it seems to work:

First, create and populate:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test_uuid (
    ->     my_uuid BINARY(16)
    ->     );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql>    
mysql> INSERT INTO test_uuid (my_uuid) VALUES (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test_uuid (my_uuid) VALUES (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test_uuid (my_uuid) VALUES (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>     
mysql> SELECT HEX(my_uuid) FROM test_uuid;
+----------------------------------+
| HEX(my_uuid)                     |
+----------------------------------+
| 5076425CA52D11EA90780242AC11000A |
| 5076D2CBA52D11EA90780242AC11000A |
| 5077762AA52D11EA90780242AC11000A |
+----------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now to test:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE test_uuid
    ->     ADD COLUMN uhex CHAR(36) COLLATE ascii_general_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE test_uuid
    ->     SET uhex = BIN_TO_UUID(my_uuid);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql>     
mysql> SELECT HEX(my_uuid), uhex FROM test_uuid;
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| HEX(my_uuid)                     | uhex                                 |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 5076425CA52D11EA90780242AC11000A | 5076425c-a52d-11ea-9078-0242ac11000a |
| 5076D2CBA52D11EA90780242AC11000A | 5076d2cb-a52d-11ea-9078-0242ac11000a |
| 5077762AA52D11EA90780242AC11000A | 5077762a-a52d-11ea-9078-0242ac11000a |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> ALTER TABLE test_uuid
    ->     DROP COLUMN my_uuid,
    ->     RENAME COLUMN uhex TO my_uuid;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test_uuid;
+--------------------------------------+
| my_uuid                              |
+--------------------------------------+
| 5076425c-a52d-11ea-9078-0242ac11000a |
| 5076d2cb-a52d-11ea-9078-0242ac11000a |
| 5077762a-a52d-11ea-9078-0242ac11000a |
+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE test_uuid\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test_uuid
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test_uuid` (
  `my_uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be

```
ALTER TABLE my_table1 MODIFY COLUMN my_uuid_column VARCHAR(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (1 +1)  STORED;
```

But you can't add many functions to a generated column, for example uuid() doesn't work, so you must do this in your code. where you generate the insert

- Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted.
- Stored procedure and function parameters are not permitted.
- Variables (system variables, user-defined variables, and stored program local variables) are not permitted.
- Subqueries are not permitted.

See official [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like most helpful things are not permitted. I've tried with `ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY COLUMN my_uuid_column VARCHAR(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (bin_to_uuid(my_uuid_column))  STORED;`. I'm getting this error: `ERROR 3107 (HY000): Generated column can refer only to generated columns defined prior to it.`.

Comment: I wonder if I shouldn't just add a new column, backfill it via SQL, then swap the names, and drop the original one.

Comment: it odesn't matter, you can't add such a generated column, Do the chage to varchar(36 and then write INSERT INOT mytable VALUES(uuid(),'a','b') or genrate it in code and then add it in the insert.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I can't do it in my code because I'm modifying an existing table. I don't want to create a generated column. I want to modify a column in a table, that already contains records, and after the conversion to `varchar` I want them to be properly formatted. This can be done easily in Postgres, but not in MySQL.

Comment: Add a NEW column, based of the existing one, `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_uuid_column_text VARCHAR(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (bin_to_uuid(my_uuid_column)) STORED`. Use the existing column for inserts/update and the generated column for retrieval.